# Custom Performance Counters triggers security exception. WHY?

Tags: azure, performancecounter

After adding custom performance counters to my application, I get the exception in the image. 
I have already added the elevated privilege, so what else should I try? I have been trying for very long to solve this issue with no result...

Thank you and please help...

```
    <Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Web role even when you have  executionContext is set to "elevated", still the role process does not get full execution permission by the OS. So when you are using Custom Performance counter in Web Role the OS does not allow this to happen and you see the exception.

What you could do is setup custom performance counter to execute with full privilege  in Role OnStart() method within RoleEntoryPoint. If you check your WebRole.cs you may find RoleEntryPoint as below to write your custom performance counter specific code:

```
// webrole.cs
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Write here your customer performance counter code
        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks AvkashChauhan. I have created the performanceCounters in Application_start in Global.Asax (I have no WebRole.cs file). What code do I need to make it execute with full privilege-or is the OnStart method more privileged that Application_start in global.asax?

Comment: Any code which is part of ASP.NET will not run in full privilege and that's why I suggested to run the counter specific code in Web role process (webrole.cs). So If you have an ASP.NET web role, you sure can have the Webrole.cs just by converting your ASP.NET app to Cloud app. The other option is to write a simple C# EXE for perf counter specific code and run as Azure Startup task.

Comment: As u mentioned you dont have webrole.cs, I just want to know how do you package ASP.NET application with VS2x? Aren't you using Azure SDK?